# Will 11.10 have Kernel 3.1 when it hits stable release or not?

Tags: kernel, 11.10

Hello I am curious if Ubuntu 11.10 will get Kernel 3.1 via updates when it hits stable release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current status of the included kernel at

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/linux-image and/or
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/ReleaseStatus/Oneiric .

Since oneiric is [scheduled](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricReleaseSchedule) to be released in less than a week, it will likely come with a 3.0 kernel. If you want to install 3.1, you can do so from the [kernel team's ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to phihag's links, the kernel version [was announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-September/034061.html) to the ubuntu development list as being 3.0